# Finding row in datatable where a specific item last changed VB

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a datatable that is filled by a tableadapter.  The table is in descending order by a date field.

What I am trying to do is find the row where a specific value last changed.  For example;

```
| ID    |    DATE       | F1    | F2    |  F3   |
|:--:   |:----------:   |:--:   |:--:   |:---:  |
|  1    | 12/31/9999    |  R    | PT    | 397   |
|  2    |  1/29/2021    |  R    | PT    |  78   |
|  3    |  1/31/2020    |  R    | FT    |  78   |
|  4    |  12/6/2019    |  R    | FT    | 397   |
|  5    |  7/19/2019    |  R    | FT    |  78   |
|  6    |  6/21/2019    |  R    | PT    |  78   |
```

So say I want to find the row where column F2 last changed.  So in this case, it last changed for row ID 2.  How can I find this row in a datatable.  Another example is F3, it last changed in ROW ID 1.

Not sure what is the best way or even how to do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How are you determining that a value has changed? Looking at this table I see no reference to a `Last Updated` column or a `Value Changed` column. Perhaps you should look in to using a LOG table - use a trigger to populate another table that contains details of the previous record before the Update

Comment: Are you talking about changes in the `DataTable` itself after you populate it from the database or are you talking about changes to the data in the database? Either way, that information doesn't exist unless you create it but how you create it will differ. Also, the suggestion about using triggers relies on your database supporting triggers. A proper RDBMS almost certainly will but file-based databases may not.